Jasmine test anchor element click without opening tab
In my Angular 17 application, I have some anchor element that has both an href for navigation and a click handler. I'm not worried about testing the href, but I'm trying write a simple "should call function" test for the click handler.
In short,
<a 
  href="some url"
  target="_blank"
  (click)="handleClick()"
  id="anchor-to-test"
>
    Click me! :)
</a>

and the associated test:
it('should call click handler when link is clicked', fakeAsync(() => {
  const onClickSpy = spyOn(component, 'handleClick');
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const link = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#anchor-to-test'));
  link.click();
  tick();

  expect(onClickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));

When I run the test, the karma/jasmine window ends up repeatedly spawning new tabs every 5 seconds or so, chewing up my system resources and preventing any tests from actually running (or at least completing).
I have tried the suggestions in these two threads to no avail, and my google-fu is failing me.

Try removing the href attrbute then performing the click!
it('should call click handler when link is clicked', fakeAsync(() => {
  const onClickSpy = spyOn(component, 'handleClick');
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const link = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#anchor-to-test'));
  link.removeAttribute("href"); // <- changed here!
  fixture.detectChanges(); // <- can work without this line, if not remove it!
  link.click();
  fixture.detectChanges(); // <- can work without this line, if not remove it!
  tick();

  expect(onClickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));


You are a life saver! I spent far too many hours trying to solve this, and all I needed was that removeAttribute (not even the other detectChanges)!
